# Symfony: services : Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a service on sSymfony, but when I use it, I get this error:

> Attempted to load class "FormSecurity" from namespace
>   "PlaformBundle\Service". Did you forget a "use" statement for another
>   namespace?

I don't understand it; could you help me to know where it could be from?

Here is my service (`PlatformBundle/Service/FormSecurity`):

```
namespace PlatformBundle\Service;
class FormSecurity
{
    public function isEmail($input)
    {
        if (preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]{1,}@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}.[a-z]{2,4}$#", $input)){
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

I use it in `src/PlatformBundle/Controller/PaymentController.php`:

```
namespace PlatformBundle\Controller;

use PlatformBundle\Entity\Customer;
use PlatformBundle\Entity\Transfer;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function checkoutAction(Request $req)
    {
        $formSecurity = $this->container->get('platform.formSecurity');
        $formSecurity->isName($post['name']);
    }
}
```

Comment: How, and where are you trying to use the FormSecurity class?

Comment: I edited the topic to show you where I use the service

Comment: Did you write "PlaformBundle\Service\FormSecurity" in your service definition? In that case you are missing a "t" in Pla**t**formBundle

Comment: That's it !!!! I was searching since 3hours and couldn't find this ! Thank you so much !